# Regular Expression Sublime Text Search and Replace

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a bunch of html files.

I am trying to find all anchor links whose href attribute does not end with slash

For example :-

```
<a href="/hello">Helllo</a>

This should match

<a href="/hello/">Helllo</a>

This should not match
```

How do i go on about making the regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make sure you only collect `href` attribute values from `<a>` elements, and to make sure you only match the link itself, you can use the following regex:

```
<a\s[^<>]*href="\K[^"]*?(?<=[^\/])(?=")
```

Or

```
<a\s[^<>]*href="\K[^"]*?(?=(?<=[^\/])")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Building on hjpotter92's answer...

Find: `href="(\S*?[^/])"`

Replace: `href="$1/"`

Answer (score 2):

The following pattern would work:

```
href="\S*?[^/]"
```

Comment: It will also capture `href` in `<link>`, and some other tags. Not sure it is what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

Find: `href="(.*?[^/])"`

Replace with: `href="$1/"`